# How to retain a space after floated :first-letter when the first letter is immediately followed by a space?

Tags: css, typography

What's an elegant solution (i.e. without adding a `&nbsp;` to the text), to introduce a space between the drop capital and the second letter, when the first word is a single letter?

I'm trying to add drop capitals to the first letter of a paragraph. The problem I am encountering is that it looks confusing if the first word is a 1 letter word, like *I*, which causes the space after to disappear.

An example is below:

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text.</p>

<p>
    I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text.
</p>
```

The solution must keep the line height the same between lines in the same way that `float: left` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution preserves the whitespace after the first character.

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

p::first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text.</p>

<p>I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text. I am some long text.</p>
```

**NB**: this requires the inner html to the `p` to be formatted on one line and the whitespace to be correct for the rest of the line, so that it doesn't interfere with the rest of the whitespace.

Comment: This could be improved by selecting **only** the text after the first letter and then applying `white-space: pre-line` to that, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit tricky to figure out, but change your CSS to this.

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

The `float: left;` attribute was removing the spacing so if you replace it with `vertical-align` instead, it keeps the space and aligns the text to the top to achieve the desired effect.

***Edit***

Here is [an example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q15px2ny/) to show it working.

Comment: This works well, until there's multiple lines, unfortunately; when it wraps, it causes a larger line height.: https://jsfiddle.net/q15px2ny/1/

Comment: What's the problem? It seems to display fine.

Comment: I've edited my comment to make that more clear: when it wraps, it causes a larger line height.